# SFINAE C++ method check

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae, decltype

I'm trying to wrap my head around SFINAE.
We're using it to check whether a class has a method called "Passengers".

With some online examples, we constructed the following template classes.

```
#ifndef TYPECHECK
#define TYPECHECK

#include "../Engine/carriage.h"

namespace TSS{

template<typename T>
class has_passengers{
private:
    typedef char one;
    typedef struct{char a[2];} two;

    template<typename C> static one test( decltype(&C::Passengers) );
    template<typename C> static two test(...);
public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(one);
};

template<typename T>
struct CarriageTypeCheck{
    static_assert(has_passengers<T>::value, "Train initialized with illegal carriage");
};

}


#endif // TYPECHECK
```

I get the part how either of the two test-methods is chosen, but what I don't understand is why `test<T>` is initialized with 0 in the following line:

```
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(one);
```

I can not see how the 0 is important for the check to work.
Another thing - why is decltype used?

Comment: You're not checking if the class has a member function `Passengers`. You're checking if it has a member `Passengers`, which might be a function, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: Good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first overloaded function (potentially) takes a pointer to a class method, as a parameter. Due to C++'s legacy from C, the value 0 is convertible to a NULL pointer, or `nullptr`. So, if SFINAE does not kick out the first overloaded function, `test<T>(0)` becomes a valid function call, and its `sizeof` is equal to `sizeof(one)`. Otherwise this resolves to the second overloaded function call.

And the short answer as to why `decltype` is used: otherwise it would not be valid C++. In a function declaration, the function's parameter must be types, specifying the types of the parameters to the function.
`&C::Passengers` is not a type (in the context of its intended use), so this would not be valid C++. `decltype()` of that automatically obtains the type of its argument, making it valid C++.

Comment: Alright. But wouldn't it be equal to 'sizeof(two)' in case T doesn't have Passengers? Then the call would be test(nullpointer) and the size would then be 2?

Comment: @BenjaminLarsen If T doesn't have Passengers, type deduction would fail, the function template will be ignored; that's how SFINAE works. There's no such rule to pass null pointer for this case, without SFINAE, you'll get a complie error.

Comment: I think I got it now! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

> I can not see how the 0 is important for the check to work.

Because `0` could be used as the argument for both cases (i.e. the two overloaded `test`); for member pointer (treated as null pointer) and variadic arguments `...`.

> Another thing - why is decltype used?

`decltype` is used for describing the type of member pointer (i.e. `&C::Passengers`) as the parameter of `test`.